# Difference between list and library

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise

I have gone through lots of articles on internet and finally decided to ask a question here to all experts.

-- Edits --
I noticed,

- I can manage event receivers in both almost same way
- I can create folders in both
- I can add custom fields, site columns to both in same way
- I can save it as list template and move it to some other site collection with data!

So, I want to ask what are what are differences when you think as an architech, developer, analyst or end user?

Comment: First please search properly and post the question here.... I got the link in 20secs of my initial search..

Comment: @Mihir, It seems you are a sharepoint expert, let me edit my question

Comment: Now question makes sense.... :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A SharePoint Library is a List which has been enhanced with a lot of features (like templates) target at storing documents/files as the main item.

You should use a library when what you want to store is documents/files to which you may have related information, workflows, ...

You should use a list when your main focus isn't a document/file, but something other to which you may relate workflows, attachments, ...

You can do (almost) anything you can do with a list to a document library

Comment: Excellent, that's what I was looking for.

Answer (score 1):

A list contains some fields and data associated with those fields.
Library is nothing but a list, but it contains some attachments. Those attachments are may be word documents, excel sheets pdfs etc..

Find this [link](http://kishansharepoint.blogspot.in/2012/06/difference-between-sharepoint-document.html)

Comment: A Library doesn't have attachments. A list may have it.